# What are my options for hardware switchable dvorak keyboards?

Tags: keyboard, dvorak

I'm a Dvorak touch typist. I need to pair with Qwerty folks.

Windows soft-keyboard switching sucks.

I'm aware that both the [Kinesis Advantage](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000LVJ9W8) and [TypeMatrix](http://www.typematrix.com/) have hardware switches that allows the computer to be in Qwerty but me to type in Dvorak.

Both are fairly pricey.

Are there other options out there?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one for $99. (hard wired)

http://www.fentek-ind.com/kbdvorak2ub.htm

Here is one for $50. (software required)

http://www.keytime.com/products/

Here is one for $20. (hard wired?)

http://shop.hooleon.com/collections/keyboards-layouts/products/keyboards-dvorak-simplified-touchdown-black-usb

Answer (score 0):

The current model is the [Matias Dvorak Keyboard](http://matias.ca/dvorak/), which is still available.  The original solution was the [Dvortyboard](http://www.ergocanada.com/ec_home/manufacturers/dvortyboards_1.html), which is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Take the plunge and buy the TypeMatrix 2030. I bought the dvorak layout model and a semi-blank skin (not sure why yet). I absolutely love this keyboard, though it did have a small learning curve to train your fingers not to stretch so far like normal keyboards.

I fully agree, software keyboard switching sucks under Windows. Gnome (Linux/FreeBSD) is a bit better, but still not as night as hardware switching.